# pandas - groupby multiple columns and get unique count of other column

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with around 20 columns. However, there are 3 particular
columns I am concerned with in this scenario.

*(date, hour, cust_id)*

Now I want to plot a graph as follows :-

1) 'x-axis' will show hours starting from 00 to 23.

2) 'y-axis' will represent count of (unique customer id) customers for that hour.

3) Each line in a graph will represent particular date for which it's plotted.

I tried following :-

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, df1 in df.groupby('date'):
    df1.groupby('hour').agg(customers = ('customer_id', 'nunique')).plot(ax=ax, label=label)
```

However, there were few issues with above :-

1) each line graph's label is getting displayed as 'customer_id' which should
   have been the date.

2) Is this graph correct?

Comment: Does something like: `df.groupby('hour')['cust_id'].nunique().reindex(range(24)).plot.bar()` get you close?

Comment: (or maybe something like: `df.groupby(['hour', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='D')])['cust_id'].nunique().unstack().plot.bar(subplots=True)`)

Comment: @JonClementsThanks for your time. Unfortunately both of above proposals are giving errors. However, issue with my solution is just label is appearing as variable name in agg ('customers').

Comment: post a few rows of your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for label, df1 in df.groupby('date'):
    ax.plot(df1.groupby('hour').agg(customers = ('customer_id', 'nunique')), label=label)
ax.legend()
```